# Scroll a particular new message div to top of the container div when a new message is typed by the user

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, scroll

I have a container div with id **myDiv** and have some divs with class **questionDiv** and some divs with class **answerDiv**. When user writes something on chatbox and press enter it will go as questionDiv and the response from other user is taken as answerDiv. I have a scrollbar using which i want to scroll the last questionDiv to come to top of the container. I have tried using scrollIntoView and also scrollTop with animation but was not successful.

Comment: We can't help you unless you show us some code.

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/deepak_modi/ppL8qvqh/). I want the last question div on top of the container as soon as new question is typed and enter key is pressed